# Place a number in a given position in a list (this case in between)

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have this three lists such as the following:

```
list1={{0.01,0.},{0.03,0.18353},{0.1,0.494987},{0.3,0.899803},{1.,1.08076},{3.,1.10593},{10.,1.04781},{10.,1.02449},{10.,0.964193},{30.,1.0602},{30.,1.04075},{30.,1.05987},{100.,1.14661},{100.,1.00639},{100.,1.09384},{300.,1.067},{300.,1.15047},{300.,1.10715},{1000.,1.05152},{1000.,1.06942},{1000.,1.17143},{3000.,1.12162},{10000.,1.13136}}

list2={{0.01,0.},{0.03,0.},{0.1,0.12702},{0.3,0.284862},{1.,0.330209},{3.,0.490592},{10.,0.864811},{30.,0.951112},{100.,0.924481},{300.,1.02702},{1000.,1.12306},{3000.,1.061},{10000.,1.08021}}

list3={{0.01,0.},{0.03,0.},{0.1,0.215019},{0.3,0.702618},{1.,1.27573},{3.,1.02397},{10.,1.1375},{10.,1.14245},{10.,0.945541},{30.,1.33324},{30.,1.07789},{30.,1.12324},{100.,1.14999},{100.,0.985026},{100.,1.1228},{300.,1.25291},{300.,1.29771},{300.,1.40179},{1000.,1.26045},{1000.,1.17871},{1000.,1.32166},{3000.,1.27041},{10000.,1.23387}}
```

How can I put a given number in between each data set of each list?. For example, if I want to place the number 10 in between in list 1 it should look like: `list1={{0.01,10,0.},{0.03,10,0.18353},{0.1,10,0.494987}...etc`. If I want to put the number 20 in between list 2 it should look like `{{0.01,20,0.},{0.03,20,0.},{0.1,20,0.12702}....etc` and so on for list 3.

Thank you in advanced,

Comment: `Riffle[#, 10] & /@ list1` and `Riffle[#, 20] & /@ list2` etc...

Comment: @kglr Thank you very much! This works great! Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[threadRiffle]
threadRiffle = MapThread[Map[Function[x, Riffle[x, #2]]]@# &, {##}] &;

threadRiffle[{list1, list2, list3}, {10, 20, xx}]
```

> ```
>  {{0.01, 10, 0.}, {0.03, 10, 0.18353}, {0.1, 10, 0.494987}, {0.3, 10, 0.899803}, 
>    {1., 10, 1.08076}, {3., 10, 1.10593}, {10., 10,  1.04781}, {10., 10, 1.02449}, 
>    {10., 10, 0.964193}, {30., 10, 1.0602}, {30., 10, 1.04075}, {30., 10, 1.05987}, 
>    {100., 10,  1.14661}, {100., 10, 1.00639}, {100., 10, 1.09384}, {300., 10,  1.067},
>    {300., 10, 1.15047}, {300., 10, 1.10715}, {1000., 10,   1.05152}, 
>    {1000., 10, 1.06942}, {1000., 10, 1.17143}, {3000., 10,  1.12162}, 
>    {10000., 10, 1.13136}},
>   {{0.01, 20, 0.}, {0.03, 20,  0.}, {0.1, 20, 0.12702}, {0.3, 20, 0.284862},
>    {1., 20,  0.330209}, {3., 20, 0.490592}, {10., 20, 0.864811},
>    {30., 20,  0.951112}, {100., 20, 0.924481}, {300., 20, 1.02702}, 
>    {1000., 20,  1.12306}, {3000., 20, 1.061}, {10000., 20, 1.08021}}, 
>    {{0.01, xx,  0.}, {0.03, xx, 0.}, {0.1, xx, 0.215019}, {0.3, xx, 0.702618}, 
>   {1.,  xx, 1.27573}, {3., xx, 1.02397}, {10., xx, 1.1375}, 
>    {10., xx,  1.14245}, {10., xx, 0.945541}, {30., xx, 1.33324}, 
>    {30., xx,  1.07789}, {30., xx, 1.12324}, {100., xx, 1.14999}, 
>    {100., xx,  0.985026}, {100., xx, 1.1228}, {300., xx, 1.25291}, 
>    {300., xx, 1.29771}, {300., xx, 1.40179}, {1000., xx, 1.26045}, 
>    {1000., xx,  1.17871}, {1000., xx, 1.32166}, {3000., xx, 1.27041}, 
>    {10000., xx, 1.23387}}}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`Insert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Insert.html) instead of `Riffle`:

```
ClearAll[threadInsert]
threadInsert[p_: 2] := MapThread[Map[Function[x, Insert[x, #2, p]]]@# &, {##}] &;

threadInsert[][{list1, list2, list3}, {10, 20, xx}] == 
  threadRiffle[{list1, list2, list3}, {10, 20, xx}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.8}};

b = {{0.2, 0.3}, {0.90, 0.4}};

c = {{0.3, 0.5}, {0.7, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.4}};
```

Using `MapThread` with `Replace`

```
MapThread[Replace[#1, {x_, y_} :> {x, #2, y}, {1}] &, {{a, b, c}, {10, 20, 30}}]
```

returns

```
{{{0.1, 10, 0.2}, {0.3, 10, 0.1}, {0.1, 10, 0.4}, {0.5, 10, 0.8}}, 
 {{0.2, 20, 0.3}, {0.9, 20, 0.4}}, 
 {{0.3, 30, 0.5}, {0.7, 30, 0.1}, {0.2, 30, 0.4}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.8}};
l2 = {{0.2, 0.3}, {0.90, 0.4}};
l3 = {{0.3, 0.5}, {0.7, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.4}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `SequenceCases`:

```
f = SequenceCases[#1, {{a_, b_}} :> {a, #2, b}] &;

MapThread[f, {{l1, l2, l3}, {10, 20, 30}}]
```

*Results*:

> {{{0.1, 10, 0.2}, {0.3, 10, 0.1}, {0.1, 10, 0.4}, {0.5, 10, 0.8}},
> {{0.2, 20, 0.3}, {0.9, 20, 0.4}},
> {{0.3, 30, 0.5}, {0.7, 30, 0.1}, {0.2, 30, 0.4}}}

Or using `Insert`:

```
f[l_, n_] := Insert[#, n, 2] & @@@ List /@ l;

MapThread[f[#1, #2] &, {{l1, l2, l3}, {10, 20, 30}}]
```

*Results*:

> {{{0.1, 10, 0.2}, {0.3, 10, 0.1}, {0.1, 10, 0.4}, {0.5, 10, 0.8}},
> {{0.2, 20, 0.3}, {0.9, 20, 0.4}},
> {{0.3, 30, 0.5}, {0.7, 30, 0.1}, {0.2, 30, 0.4}}}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way

```
{#1, 10, #2} & @@@ list1
```

or use `MapApply` introduced in Mathematica 13.1 (it's the same function, @@@ is syntactic sugar)

```
MapApply[{#1, 10., #2} &, list1]
```

Both give

> {{0.01, 10, 0.}, {0.03, 10, 0.18353}, {0.1, 10, 0.494987} ... {10000., 10, 1.13136}}